# Mongoose find({}) not returning anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to locally analyze my users from my database, but for some reason, the following code does not log anything, suggestions?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURIDEV = 'mongodb://MY-URI';
const MONGO = mongoURIDEV;

mongoose.connect(MONGO);
const schema = require('../schema/users');

async function main() {
const users = await schema.find({});
    console.log(users.length);
}

main().catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

edit: here is the schema being used:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const usersSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  uid: String,
  gender: String,
  forward: String,
  keyword: String,
  placeType: String,
  profile_pic: String,
  referenceName: String,
  order_restaurant: String,
  order_people: String,
  order_time: String,
  order_timestamp: Object,
  order_email: String,
  order_phone: String,
  order_contact: []
}, { collection: 'Users' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);
```

it is the same one used in production is it works just fine

Comment: can you share the code of schema/ users?

Comment: just added it, see above. thanks

Comment: Did you tried to use exec? const users = await schema.find({}).exec();

Comment: I tried using exec, even tried again using your specific code. still doesn't work

Comment: Are you successfully connected to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

try this **.exec()** returns promise

```
async function main() {
const users = await schema.find({}).exec();
    console.log(users.length);
    return users;
}

main().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this  you miss to wirte exec()

`async function main() {
const users = await schema.find({}).exec(){
    console.log(users.length);
}`

Comment: Yes it is the same as what Rahul Sharma suggested, does not work for me